# peewee CharField() is not storing information

Tags: python, sqlite, peewee

This is my model class:

```
class Product(BaseModel):
    product_name = peewee.CharField(max_length=100, default="", index=True)
    description = peewee.CharField(max_length=100, index=True)
    price = peewee.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    quantity_in_stock = peewee.IntegerField(
        constraints=[peewee.Check("quantity_in_stock >= 0")]
    )
    owners = peewee.ManyToManyField(Buyer, backref="owned_products")
    tags = peewee.ManyToManyField(Tag, backref="product_tag")
```

and this is my function to add products to my database:

```
def populate_test_database():
    example_user1 = models.Buyer.create(
        username="Anita89",
        name="Anita Aniton",
        address="1987 March St",
        billing_info="MasterCard",
    )
    example_user2 = models.Buyer.create(
        username="Peter12",
        name="Peter Peterson",
        address="12 April St",
        billing_info="Bank Account",
    )

    product1 = models.Product.create(
        product_name="So",
        description="Bar of soap",
        price=12.99,
        quantity_in_stock=50,
    )
    product3 = models.Product.create(
        product_name="Shampoo",
        description="Bottle of shampoo",
        price=8.49,
        quantity_in_stock=30,
    )
    product2 = models.Product.create(
        product_name="Beer 0",
        description="Beer in a bottle",
        price=8.99,
        quantity_in_stock=60,
    )

    product1.owners.add(example_user1)
    product2.owners.add(example_user2)

    tag1 = models.Tag.create(name="Tag1")
    tag2 = models.Tag.create(name="Tag2")

    product1.tags.add(tag1)
    product1.tags.add(tag2)
    product2.tags.add(tag2)
    product3.tags.add(tag1)

    transaction1 = models.Transaction.create(
        user=example_user1,
        product=product1,
        date="2023-09-10",
        products_purchased=5,
    )
    transaction2 = models.Transaction.create(
        user=example_user2,
        product=product2,
        date="2023-09-11",
        products_purchased=2,
    )

    print("Test data populated.")
```

The product_name is not being stored, this is the outcome I am getting:

-Product Name:
-Description: Bar of soap
-Price: 12.99
-Quantity in Stock: 50

-Product Name:
-Description: Bottle of shampoo
-Price: 8.49
-Quantity in Stock: 30

Can someone please have a look at my code and see if they can help me with this?

https://github.com/evi8n/Betsys_webshop_assignment.git

My tutor said I should just set it to default="" but that kind of defeats the purpose of creating a product database...

Thank you in advance ^_^

Evi

Comment: Your example code is using `product.name` and not `product.product_name` - possibly there's some mixup? https://github.com/evi8n/Betsys_webshop_assignment/blob/main/betsy-webshop/main.py#L11-L38

Comment: That was another thing I needed to fix, thank you. Everything seems to be working fine now. I also updated it on Github.

Answer (score 1):

In my transaction class I was using a backref for the product: product = peewee.ForeignKeyField(Product, backref="product_name")

Somehow this was conflicting with the product_name variable in my product class. Changing this backref to name_of_product solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Data is stored just fine, I think there may be a mixup in your code about where that data is actually stored:

```
from peewee import *

db = SqliteDatabase(':memory:')

class Buyer(db.Model):
    name = CharField()

class Tag(db.Model):
    tag = CharField(unique=True)

class Product(db.Model):
    product_name = CharField(max_length=100, default='', index=True)
    description = CharField(max_length=100)
    price = DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    quantity_in_stock = IntegerField(constraints=[
        Check('quantity_in_stock >= 0')])
    owners = ManyToManyField(Buyer, backref='owned_products')
    tags = ManyToManyField(Tag, backref='tagged_products')

db.create_tables([Product, Buyer, Tag, Product.owners.through_model,
                  Product.tags.through_model])

Product.create(
    product_name='So',
    description='Bar of soap',
    price=12.99,
    quantity_in_stock=50)

for p in Product.select():
    print(p.product_name)
```

This correctly prints "So".